# RTTR - Reflect existing methods from a library

Tags: c++, reflection

I am trying to use `rttr` to add reflection to existing OpenGL drawing commands. I am on Windows 10, VS 2019.

This is in my entry file, above `main`:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <rttr/registration>

using namespace rttr;

static const GLenum TGL_LINES = GL_LINES;
void tBegin(GLenum mode) {
    glBegin(mode);
}
void tEnd() {
    glEnd();
}
void tVertex2f(float x, float y) {
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}

RTTR_REGISTRATION
{
    using namespace rttr;
    // with registration lines removed, program runs without error
    registration::property_readonly("GL_LINES", &TGL_LINES);
    registration::method("begin", &tBegin);
    registration::method("end", &tEnd);
    registration::method("vertex2f", &tVertex2f);
}
```

I am able to build successfully but at runtime upon registering the reflections, VS gives an Exception Unhandled dialog popup for `ucrtbase.dll`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7677CAA2 (ucrtbase.dll) in glfw-node.exe:
An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

When the `registration::property_readonly` and `registration::method` lines are removed, the program runs without issue, including OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just saw your question today, also I have not use OpenGL before.

1.
Have you tested to see if RTTR works in 2019, it says it has not been tested for 2019?

2.
In your main function, are you invoking the functions via reflection? if you are. please can I see it. I think this might be an invoking problem.

I have taken a look at the [Tutorial Page](https://www.rttr.org/doc/master/tutorial_page.html) for methods and functions.
And it says to invoke a method you do this. 
For example, to reflectively invoke a your **tBegin** function, you need to do this `type::invoke("begin", {TGL_LINES})`, the second argument is are a list of values you tell **RTTR** to use to invoke your **tBegin** function.

I am sorry I cannot be of me help right now, but I need more information.